# Missing details in Wiki-proof about continued fractions of $\sqrt{N}$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

I came across the Wiki-proof sites and I wanted to find out a proof that the continued fraction of $\sqrt{N}$, where $N$ is a positive integer, not being a perfect square, has the form $[a,\overline {r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n,2a}]$

In Wiki-proof, I only found the proof that the continued fraction expansion must eventually become periodic. But two things are missing :

> How can I prove that the period starts immediately after the first entry $a=\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ ?
>
> How can I prove that the period ends with the entry $2a$ and that the corresponding convergent $\frac{p}{q}$ is the fundamental solution of the Pell-equation $p^2-Nq^2=\pm1$ ?

Please answer with a proof directly written down and not just with a link!

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continued_Fraction_Expansion_of_Irrational_Square_Root

Comment: I was struggling exactly with the same thing lately: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289017/what-causes-the-last-item-of-the-simple-periodic-continued-fraction-of-the-squar

Answer (score 3):

I will answer the first two parts of your question, i.e., $\sqrt N$ has a continued fraction of the form $[\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; \overline{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, 2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor}]$.

We will assume that we already know that a [quadratic irrational number has a periodic continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Relation_to_quadratic_irrationals).

First, we need the following theorem of Galois, the proof of which I take from Theorem 7.20 in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991:

**Theorem of Galois.** The continued fraction of the quadratic irrational number $\xi$ is purely periodic if $\xi > 1$ and $-1 < \xi' < 0$, where $\xi'$ is the [conjugate](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Conjugate_pair) of $\xi$.

Proof: Recall the [inductive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) for expanding $\xi = \xi_0$ into a continued fraction:
$$a_i = \lfloor \xi_i \rfloor, \qquad \xi_{i+1} = \frac{1}{\xi_i - a_i}.$$

Invert and take conjugates of the latter equation to obtain
$$\frac{1}{\xi'_{i+1}} = \xi'_i - a_i.$$
Now $a_i \ge 1$.  Hence, if $\xi'_i < 0$, then $1/\xi'_{i+1} < -1$, and we have $-1 < \xi'_{i+1} < 0$.  Because $-1 < \xi'_0 < 0$ by hypothesis, we see by mathematical induction that $-1 < \xi'_i < 0$ is true for all $i$.  Then by the previous equation,
$$0 < -\frac{1}{\xi'_{i+1}} - a_i < 1, \qquad a_i= \left\lfloor -\frac{1}{\xi'_{i+1}} \right\rfloor.$$
[Because $\xi$ is a quadratic irrational number, it has a periodic continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction#Relation_to_quadratic_irrationals), so $\xi_j = \xi_k$ for some integers $j$ and $k$ with $0 < j < k$.  Then we also have $\xi'_j = \xi'_k$, and

\begin{align}
a_{j-1} & = \left\lfloor -\frac{1}{\xi'_j} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor -\frac{1}{\xi'_k}\right\rfloor = a_{k-1}\\
\xi_{j-1} & = a_{j-1} + \frac{1}{\xi_j} = a_{k-1} + \frac{1}{\xi_k} = \xi_{k-1}.
\end{align}
Hence, $\xi_j = \xi_k$ implies $\xi_{j-1} = \xi_{k-1}$.  A $j$-fold iteration of that implication gives $\xi_0 = \xi_{k-j}$, and we have $\xi = \xi_0 = [\overline{a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_{k-j-1}}]$, which completes the proof of the theorem of Galois.

The rest of the answer comes from Proposition 32 of ["Continued Fractions, Pell's Equation, and Transcendental Numbers" by Jeremy Booher](http://math.stanford.edu/~jbooher/expos/continued_fractions.pdf):

Because
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt N - \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor} > 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad -1 < \frac{1}{-\sqrt N - \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor} < 0,$$
the continued fraction of $\upsilon_1 = 1/(\sqrt N - \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor)$ is purely periodic by the theorem of Galois, so $\upsilon_0 = \sqrt N$ has the form $[\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; \overline{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}}]$ where $n+1$ denotes the length of the shortest period in that expansion.  (I am using the notation $\upsilon_0$ and $\upsilon_1$ because $\upsilon_0 = \sqrt N$ and $\upsilon_1 = 1/(\sqrt N - \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor)$ are related by the inductive definition above for expanding $\upsilon_0$ into a continued fraction.)  Also, $\sqrt N + \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor = [2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; \overline{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}}]$. Moreover,
$$\sqrt N + \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor > 1, \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
-1 < \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor - \sqrt N < 0,$$
so the continued fraction of $\sqrt N + \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor$ is purely periodic by the theorem of Galois, which means that the period (of length $n + 1$) starts at the beginning of the expansion.  We therefore have more ways to express the continued fraction for $\sqrt N + \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt N + \lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor & = [2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; \overline{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}}]\\
 & = [\overline{2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n}, a_{n+1}, \ldots]\\
 & = [\overline{2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n}].
\end{align}
We see from the last two continued fractions that $a_{n+1}$ begins the second period, so $a_{n+1}$ has the same value as the first integer of the first period, i.e., $a_{n+1} = 2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor$.  Substituting for $a_{n+1}$ in the continued fraction for $\sqrt N$ concludes the proof:
$$\sqrt N = [\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor; \overline{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, 2\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor}].$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1)